# Small scale usage, is solr or elastic search more suitable?

Tags: elasticsearch, solr

For fairly small scale usage with maybe 100-300K documents to store, would solr or elastic search be more suitable?

Let's ignore feature set for a moment as the use case is very trivial, but I am more concerned with the constraints of this working on a single VM with fairly low (1 GB) RAM on it.

Comment: For simple use and < 1M of not-too-large documents, you can easily run Solr with 512MB of heap. Maybe < 256MB with some tweaking. I don't know about ES, but i _guess_ it's the same.

Answer (score 1):

my gut feeling is that carefully optimizing your index to the strictly needed, like:

- index only what is needed
- remove all stopwords if possible
- disable norms
- enable docvalues
- use filters and make sure are cached
- ...all that stuff

  would be more efficient than choosing Solr or ES. Also if your use case is very simple, and are looking at very low resources, maybe it is worth going with plain Lucene?

Comment: well I want to start off simple, and then eventually use from features.